# Prototyp JavaScript, get to much new forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, prototype

I build a collecting form in Symfony.
I have a Mainform and inside a Subform.

I can add new Mainform or inside new Subforms.
It works fine with my script.

The only thing and I don't know why is, that it add multiple subforms when I add more mainforms.

As example:
I have 3 mainforms.
If I click to add in the last one I get one subform. If I click in the one before the last one I get 2 new subforms and in the first one I get 3 new subforms.

It looks like - and this is also the outcome of my console.log test - that it runs on click the function multiple like the number of mainforms.

But I don't know why???

Here is my Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.categories-wrapper');
        $wrapper.on('click', '.js-category-delete', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).closest('.js-category-item')
                .fadeOut()
                .remove();
        });
        $wrapper.on('click', '.js-category-add', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
            var prototype = $wrapper.data('prototype');

            // get the new index
            var index = $wrapper.data('index');

            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__main__/g, index);

            // increase the index with one for the next item
            $wrapper.data('index', index + 1);

            // Info
            $indexCount = index;
            console.log('Index:' + $indexCount);

            // Display the form in the page before the "new" link
            $(this).before(newForm);

            //

            subcategories();

        });
    });

    //


    function subcategories(){
        $('.subcategories-wrapper').each(function(i) {
            var count = (i+1);

            $(this).addClass("item"+count);

            var $subwrapper = $('.subcategories-wrapper.item'+count);
            $subwrapper.on('click', '.js-subcategory-delete', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).closest('.js-subcategory-item')
                    .fadeOut()
                    .remove();
            });
            $subwrapper.on('click', '.js-subcategory-add', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
                var prototype = $subwrapper.data('prototype');

                // get the new index
                var index = $subwrapper.data('index');
                console.log(count);

                // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
                // instead be a number based on how many items we have
                var subnewForm = prototype.replace(/__sub__/g, index);

                // increase the index with one for the next item
                $subwrapper.data('index', index + 1);

                // Info
                console.log('Mainndex:' + $indexCount);

                // Display the form in the page before the "new" link
                $(this).before(subnewForm);
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        subcategories();

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else runs in this here is the answer I found self. The problem is the event.

Add a off() before on and it runs perfect.

```
$subwrapper.off().on('click', '.js-subcategory-add', function(e) {
```